# Should the tags 'saying' and 'proverbs' be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I noticed that these tags are very similar and effectively have the same meaning.

I searched in two search engines `define proverb` and `define saying`, here are the results:

**Yahoo**

> a short pithy saying in general use, stating a general truth or piece of advice.
>   a short, pithy expression that generally contains advice or wisdom.

**Google**

> a short, well-known pithy saying, stating a general truth or piece of advice.
>   a short, pithy, commonly known expression which generally offers advice or wisdom.

Going by these obvious similarities, shouldn't they be merged?

If they are to be merged, which should be a synonym of the other?
'Saying' is slightly more popular than 'proverb' ([Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+proverb%2C+a+saying&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ca%20proverb%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20proverb%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20proverb%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20Proverb%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ca%20saying%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20saying%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20saying%3B%2Cc0)) but proverb sounds more academic.

Comment: Note also [tag:aphorism] and [tag:expressions], which overlap, as does [tag:idioms].

Answer (score 5):

I suggest proverb and saying are quite different both in meaning and use.
A proverb is typically advice or an old expression of a common truth. If a new phrase were coined, such as "Make America Great" I would suggest it would not be labelled a proverb but a saying.
A saying is a current phrase or short statement in popular use that typically has a meaning beyond that strictly associated with each discreet word. A saying may see a change in the underlying meaning predicated on use and application. A proverb is usually less mutable as its meaning is captured in respected or accepted texts with an associated explaination.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably right that [saying](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saying) and [proverb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proverb) are probably the same
thing and so should be synonymized and merged.

Then again, so too is [epigram](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epigram) which I bet is my fault although I haven't looked.

Those should all be in the plural, and there should be one tag to rule them all, one tag to find them.

At the point it’s probably best I not mention *gnome, adage,
epigram, aphorism, apothegm, apophthegm, sententia,* nor *paroemia*.

Nor shall I drift into *expression, platitude, bromide, refrain, byword, witticism,
quip, catchphrase, maxim, mantra, truism, axiom, homily, precept, brocard,
dictum, tenet, motto, slogan, jingle, saw, chestnut, cliché, banality,* or 
*parable.*

Nor *tweet*.

Comment: Well, perhaps we need an organised tag clean-up. Should we try a site-wide clean-up effort?